# How to enable all login methods?

Tags: windows-10-preview, microsoft-surface-pro-3

At the moment, after looking everywhere I could think of in the Control Panel, I could only set the authorization method to the old, boring type-in-your-secret-string one. I recall that a friend of mine showed me once that one could log in by e.g. taking a picture of ones face alternatively by swiping across the screen following a preset pattern.

Where are those features activated?

Comment: try if this still works in Windows 10: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/personalize-pc-tutorial